# Is there Zakah on amanah?

Tags: fiqh, zakat

If person A kept some money with person B for safety over which more than a lunar year has passed, who is liable to pay the zakah?

***Is it Person A or Person B?***

Comment: Clearly person A. If person A gives something in box say Gold, person B don't have right to open the box and see in it, so how he can know that he has to pay zakah or not, and how much.

Comment: @AliAdravi you have misunderstood the context. I never mentioned about any box or the money been unknown. Person A handed the money to Person B for save keeping (emergency fund for his mother). Both are aware of the exact amount that was handed over.